# Is it possible to improve this zmq architecture?

Tags: networking, architecture, zeromq, distributed

### Intro:

In the below architecture, there are three key components.
[image]

1. **Users** - Machines where user application is running.
2. **Applications** - which are running inside the remote server.
3. **Gateway/Broker** - Required  for isolation between user devices and server applications.

**Message flow between user device and server application should happen as below**

1. User shall transmit message to remote server, which will be used by
   the one or more server applications.
2. Application shall broadcast/publish message to all connected
   users.
3. Application shall send message to a particular user device
   (Unicast).

In addition, one or more users will be connected or disconnected to the server arbitrarily and one or more application will be spawned or terminated arbitrarily.

---

For the above problem statement, I have designed the below zmq architecture.

[image]

The Gateway/Broker handles arbitrary assignments of users and applications and also provides the required isolation. It publishes user messages to all applications. It also aggregates all messages needed to be sent to users from applications via a **`SUB`** socket.

The application sends a two part message, the first part is the user identity and the second part is the actual message. The Gateway/Broker transmits that message to a user, based on identity. A special identity for a broadcast will be created, the gateway, if has received broadcast identity, will publish the message to all users via **`PUB`** socket.

The user connects to both **`ROUTER`** and **`PUB`** sockets in gateway. Fair queued data will be received from both sockets. While sending, the message will be sent to only gateway's **`ROUTER`** socket, not **`PUB`** socket.

---

### Questions:

**`Q1`**: Is there any flaw with above architecture?

**`Q2`**: Is it possible to improve it more?
Metric assumed for the `Q2`:

1. The users and applications are dynamic in nature, they connect and disconnect on their own, the design **should withstand** that,
2. User reports its status periodically to server, design **should facilitate latency of less than `333 [ms]`** ( a user, connected to server over internet, WAN connectivity btw user and server provides a latency much less than `333 [ms]` )
3. **Lossless transmission** between server and users ( ACKing at backend, retransmission if lost )

Comment: What is the core-utility, against which you compare respective design approaches -- what quantitative, fact-based attributes do you evalutate and what aggregation metrics do you use to compare individual solutions & to distinguish between a better and a worse alternative?

Comment: @user3666197I am new to zmq, learning since past week. So at first, i would like to check whether my understanding is correct and the base design is without any major design issue.

Comment: @user3666197But the factors with which the various designs will compared are 1. The users and applications are dynamic in nature, they connect and disconnect on their own, the design should withstand that, 2. User report its status periodically to server, design should facilitate latency of less than 333ms (user connected to server over internet, WAN connectivity btw user and server provides a latency much less than 333ms) 3. Lossless transmission between server and users (acking at backend, retransmission if lost)

Answer (score 3):

You can try Malamute, which gives you what you need and more like credit-flow, keep-alive, tracking.

Malamute is small broker based on zeromq and part of the zeromq community. You can run Malamute as a component inside your application and don't need a dedicate service or daemon for it.

If you are using C or C++ that is no brainer as it integrate naturally. It also has binding for a lot more languages.

https://github.com/zeromq/malamute

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i have started exploring malamute. But are there any stable release for this project? or is it still under development? Could you share some review of malamute from users, if you have any?

Comment: Is it possible to use malamute in Android? or Is it possible to develop a minimal malamute client using jeroMQ?

Comment: I think you can use Malamute client in android. Try to ask in the zeromq list. The project is used in production and pretty active.